# What does 'Gangnam Style' mean?

Tags: word-choice

Does PSY attribute his fashion to his district Gangnam? I've been hearing people nowadays going 'I have the Gangnam Style'. Are they meaning they have adopted the cultures of Korea, Gangnam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Gangnam” is an area in South Korea, specifically a small area in Seoul, South Korea, home to about 1% of the population of Seoul and is about the size of Manhattan.  It is known for its wealthy, “new money”, inhabitants.  (The region has only very recently become extremely upscale, with a gradual upswing in the last half century or so. Before that, there really wasn’t much there but farmland.)
How wealthy do you have to be to live in Gangnam?  The average price of an apartment there costs around 3/4 of a million dollars per year.  For reference, the average South Korean household’s annual income is about $40,000.
So “Gangnam Style” simply is referencing this sort of elite, “new money”, wealthy culture and lifestyle that has sprung up around the region.  As pop critic Kim Zakka, who lives in Seoul, said “Gangnam inspires both envy and distaste.  Gangnam residents are South Korea’s upper class, but South Koreans consider them self-interested, with no sense of nobility.”
Or, as Park Jae-sang (PSY, who himself was from a wealthy family and grew up close to Gangnam) said, Gangnam residents are seen as “good-looking because of plastic surgery, stylish because they can splurge on luxury goods, and slim thanks to yoga and personal trainers.”  Sounds a bit like wealthy people from Los Angeles…

Read [more about Gangnam Style here.](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/12/what-does-gangnam-style-mean/#VkIY1vQidgXoFUHd.99)

Cited: (http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/12/what-does-gangnam-style-mean/#VkIY1vQidgXoFUHd.99)

Comment: Rents in Gangnam are obviously high, but I think you've somewhat overstated things. According to [this page](http://ibnlive.in.com/news/gangnam-style-so-where-exactly-is-gangnam/299558-2.html) *The average Gangnam apartment **costs** about $716,000, a sum that would take an average South Korean household 18 years to earn.* But at least they'd *own* the property if they paid that much - it's not "annual rent". For comparison, in the UK overall, houses cost about 6 times the average wage (4 times average *household income*).

Comment: Sorry, I might have overstated quite a bit.